# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException

Tags: java, jackson, pojo

I am trying to create java beans from xml. 
Below is my xml :

```
<CommunicationFile count="1">
    <Communication>
        <creationDate>2017-11-25</creationDate>
        <Document>
            <objectReference>111111</objectReference>
        </Document>
        ..........
    </Communication>
</CommunicationFile>
```

Here is my Java files. I created exact mapping to variables to the xml using jackson XML property :

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "CommunicationFile")
public final class CommunicationFile {
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "count", isAttribute = true)
private String count;
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Communication")
private Communication[] communication;

    ..Standard setter and getters...

}
------
```

Below is the wrapper class for `Communication`. This class is for nested elements in `CommunicatonFile`.

```
public final class Communication {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "creationDate")
    private String creationDate;
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Document")
    private Document document;
   .. standard setter and getters
}
```

Trying to map xml to pojo using jackson APIs:

```
XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader sr = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("billing.xml"));

XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
sr.next(); // to point to <root>
sr.next(); // to point to root-element under root
CommunicationFile comm = mapper.readValue(sr, CommunicationFile.class);
```

Getting below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "creationDate" (class com.pm.communication.CommunicationFile), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "Communication", "count"])
 at [Source: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.wssec.WSSXMLInputFactory$WSSStreamReaderProxy@981206cc; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.pm.communication.CommunicationFile["creationDate"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:51)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:839)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1045)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1352)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1330)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:125)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3708)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2071)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.readValue(XmlMapper.java:205)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.readValue(XmlMapper.java:180)
    at com.pm.docmaker.tpd.Parser.main(Parser.java:25)
```

I am not sure why `jackson` is looking for `creationDate` in `CommunicationFile` class. `creationDate` is in `Communication` Class. I am uing jackson 2.6.7 API's.

Comment: Is it a typo? _CreationDate_ in code vs. _creationDate_ in XML

Comment: I tried with small 'c' and Capital 'C' in creation date. Getting same error for both.

Answer (score 0):

The XML in the question has an unwrapped collection of `Communication` elements. This has to be specified on the annotation. E.g.:

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Communication", useWrapping = false)
private Communication[] communication;
```

Based on the current annotation the XML should be:

```
<CommunicationFile count="1">
  <Communication>
    <Communication>
      <creationDate>2017-11-25</creationDate>
      ...
    </Communication>
    <Communication>
      <creationDate>2018-07-11</creationDate>
      ...
    </Communication>
  </Communication>
```

Jackson is confused with the lack of a second level `<Communication>` and apparently/bizarrely considers `creationDate` to be part of `CommunicationFile`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my xml is like below. I have only one Communcation element.  <CommunicationFile count="1">
  <Communication>
         <creationDate>2017-11-25</creationDate>
      ...
    </Communication>
      <creationDate>2018-07-11</creationDate>
      ...
    </Communication>

Comment: That's exactly why you have to use `useWrapping = false` in the annotation. Have you tried that ?